# Responsive Design - Database Generated Icons / Images

Tags: php, css, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

On the home page of a site I am working on we have about 50 large icons / images generated on the screen from the database, I currently have them called out 5 across and then I put in a BR tag to go to the next line (using PHP and a counter). My issue is the design needs to be responsive so if you shrink the screen a little it will save fit 3 on the first line and then 2 on the next line then the PHP generated BR tag kicks in so we get a space.

What is the best way to get around this so it works each time no matter the screen size? I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and cakephp for the coding.

The best way to see what I mean is on the website itself: http://www.beanclaim.com/

Thanks

The Current PHP CODE IS:

```
// LOOPING THROUGH ALL OF THE INDUSTRY ICONS AND BUILDING A LINK FOR THEM
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
if (isset($industry_icons)) 
{ 
    $i=0;
    foreach ($industry_icons as $industry) 
    { 

        echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image($industry['Industry']['image_path'],
            array(
                'width' => '180',
                'style' => 'margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px;')),
            array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'register', 'industries' => $industry['Industry']['id']),
            array('escape' => false));


      $i++;
      if($i % 5 == 0)
      {
        echo "<br />"; 
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1.5mb front page ouch! not every one has a fibre internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<br/>` tags. And your problem is solved. The images will automatically adjust based on your container div size.

Comment: Thanks, how do I go about centering the icons? If you reduce the width of the page down to say 1 or 2 icons across you notice they are not centered within the area.

Comment: I think you got two things going there. After you get below about 755px, you are no longer "snapping" to the specific width. Also, the two drop downs and the button are in a table be preventing that section from shrinking down smaller. Put each of the drop downs and the button in a floating div to allow them to stack up on top of each other instead of be side by side when you get that small.